# How can I setup second Wordpress for an AddOn domain?

Tags: wordpress

I already have a blog which is installed in a sub folder and with its .htaccess and index.php in the root of my host. My host allows me to run multiple websites with my single host account and I added a second domain as an addon domain.

My problem is, I am having trouble to run my second blog using the addon domain. I tried installing it in separate folder and I can access it with `www.addondomain.com/foldername/`, but cannot access it from `www.addondomain.com`.

How can I do that? I tried changing the wordpress site URL from the dashboard.

Comment: It looks like your addondomain is _parked_ on top of your main domain? However, add-on domains usually point at subdomains of the main domain (which themselves point to sub folders). In which case `www.addondomain.com/foldername/` wouldn't be possible if /foldername is a directory off the document root of the main domain. Is this how it is setup? Did you use the addondomain when installing Wordpress?

Comment: W3d,  I use the add-on domain to install the second wordpress. I added the add-on domain directed to sub-folder of the document root. I think,the better way to acheive what I am trying to do is to use the Wordpress network?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you dumped your Wordpress files into a sub folder of the root folder you pointed your new addon domain to in the host. You should take a closer look cause that sounds like what's going on. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I learnt some leasons through the hard way! I hope, some more people may happen to attempt what I have been trying to do and I am sharing here what I experienced.

I have been trying to create two wordpress blogs like `www.myblog1.com` and `www.myblog2.com from` one wordpress install located in a sub-folder(not at the document root). As indicated [here,](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) it is not possible to create network of Sub-domain based blogs like `www.myblog1.com` while the wordpress install is in a sub-folder. I can only create path based blogs like `www.myblog1.com/blog/` while the wordpress install is in a sub-folder.

I re-installed the wordpress at the document root and setup it for multisite following the procedures indicated at [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)

Again, Any attempt to convert an existing stand alone wordpress blog must be done after a careful backup of the existing blog. I run in a situation of having no access to my blog but, I started my work with full back of my wordpress. The backup saved my day.